# c# architectural: functionality of a visual component

Tags: c#, winforms, architecture, components

I have a feeling that I am turning my component in a big ball of mud, as I have no experience in properly structuring this kind of application (more used to database application stacks).

I am programming something like a visual editor - basically, some graphic background which you can navigate (zoom/pan), add some objects over it and manipulate those - move them around, delete, move various elements of each object separately, etc.

It is structurally a visual component (derived from something rather generic). It holds a reference to the project model which represents everything in terms of data the editor manipulates. Plus, there is a number of managers that implement the logic of what can happen and what does happen to the project's data as response to user's actions. So far so good.

There is also a number of properties and events on the component itself which implement the particularities of user interactions. For example, rendering the background, rendering all the objects over it, embellishing selected objects with control elements (drag handles, etc).

Now the question is: such details of implementation of the graphics and interactions with user - what is a better approach than just lumping all this code inside the component class? I thought of a couple of options:

1. Maintaining a big component class where everything is in, possibly while separating it into several partial classes to separate responsibilities that way.
2. Implementing rendering and interaction logic into separate manager-like classes and passing the component's instance as a parameter - ??? - somehow the manager needs to know quite a lot about the component's state, that's the problem. Many properties there are inherently private and have no business being visible to the rest of WinForms application. So that's kind of an issue...

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: 3 - put an `ElementHost` and use WPF, which supports DataBinding and allows you to have proper separation of UI and data, allows a much greater level of customization and does not need the horrible hacks required by winforms to do anything, e.g "owner draw".

Comment: UI and data are properly separated in my case. Data and what happens to it as a result of user interactions - I am quite happy with. I have a complex custom editor and would just like to know how to structure its logic better. Not sure we're talking about the same problems, HighCore. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: it's really hard for me to tell what you've got going on here... That said, #1 should raise a big red flag, in general, it's better to have lots of smaller classes than larger ones. Partial classes don't separate responsibilities, just the file location of the code. You're still left with a single, large class that probably does way too much. As for #2, you could pass the component as a parameter and still have private properties... If a manager class needs to know some piece of information and act on it, should it really be private?

Comment: From the field: I'm trying the second approach here, basically extracting logic of presentation into manager classes which take component as parameter and it's actually looking quite sexy. My goal is to have the control itself only maintain the state, provide API for the host form and dispatch interactions with user. And complex drawing and handling editing operations (on clickety-click level) will be outside in the managers.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use separate classes and pass stuff around, *only* to prevent a giant code file.

You mention your component references the project model - you could define the visual characteristics as a control, and have a DTO-type of class you fill with data that needs to be displayed. That would be in line with other WinForms components; for instance the `ListViewItems` for the  `ListView` control.

Alternatively you could have the above created control subclassed, and put the reference to the model there.

Otherwise, if you really end up creating a giant class, I would prefer partial classes with clear names (`MyComponent_Events.cs` etc) over a single giant scroll wheel killer.

Comment: Well, it's not only to fight the size of the code, obviously. Achieving some "testability" is also a goal. Currently I don't even have any idea how to approach this code with unit testing (it was conceived as a part of experimenting/brainstorming, so no TDD in this particular area yet)

Comment: Unit testing the visible properties of controls is a pain, so I would definitely try to isolate that from the rest of the project, and make sure the control does not reference the model. Also edited my answer.